# How to separate two words in php from a database

Tags: php, sql

I have a string saved in my database with the value `hello world`. I want to extract this data from my database and display `hello` on one line and `world` on the line below it.

How can I do this using php?

Comment: You can use php explode to break this word. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to Niranjan's solution is to replace all occurrences of a space with `"<br>"`, and then echo the string. You can avoid using a loop this way, although your output will remain the same.

```
echo str_replace(' ', '<br>', 'Hello to all of my friends!');
```

This would print all the words on a separate line, when rendered on a webpage.

Comment: This is definitely best (one liner) solution. @Biriju, you should accept this answer as solution.

Answer (score 4):

use `explode()`

```
$a = explode(" ","hello world");

foreach($a as $key => $val) {

      echo $val."<br>";
}
```